# generic maximum function in Java

Tags: java, generics

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<? extends T> coll){
    // return max;
}
```

I see why `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` makes a sense. But, I am not sure why an argument `List<? extends T> coll` is important.

Why `List<T> coll` is not sufficient?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java will help you to understand the concept.

Comment: Do those duplicates really answer this question? As for me (without having tested it either way), I tend to agree with OP in seeing no reason why `List<T>` would not suffice in this case.

Comment: Where did you see this code?

Comment: @Thilo It's not dissimilar to `Collections.max()`